# Why do I get "fstream not found" while compiling with eosiocpp?

Tags: smart-contract

Why do I get this when trying to compile a contract?

```
root@caf8aac11bb2:/work/eosio.token# eosiocpp -o eosio.token.wast eosio.token.cpp 
eosio.token.cpp:8:10: fatal error: 'fstream' file not found
#include "fstream"
     ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.
Simply, file operations are not possible in eos. They aren't meant for that. These type of actions can be fulfilled through the front end. The blockchain coding is like querying a database. ie. Only read and write are allowed.